# 特定のカラムに特定のメソッドを一括で適用する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

特定のカラムにメソッドを適用して一括で更新する時に`find_each`を使って如何にように書いているのですが、もっとよい書き方はありますか？

```
Post.find_each do |post|
  post.update_column(:foo, post.foo&.downcase)
end
```

`update_all`は更新後の値が固定の場合だけしか使えませんし、何か定番の書き方があるかと思い質問いたしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

一括更新はバルクアップデートやバルク更新などと言われています。

RDBMSがMySQLやPostgreSQLであればバルクインサート（一括挿入）と共に対応しています。
ただし、Railsの場合はActiveRecord自体が未対応なのでgemに頼るかSQL直書きになります。

> 特定のカラムにメソッドを適用して一括で更新する時に`find_each`を使って如何にように書いているのですが、もっとよい書き方はありますか？

あなたの言う「よい書き方」とは何でしょうか？そのコードの目的は何でしょうか？
それがほとんど実行されない一時的なものであれば、現状の分かりやすいコードのままにすることをお勧めします。
もし頻繁に発生する処理だとすれば、まずは一括更新に頼らない方法を模索しましょう。今回の場合であれば`post.foo&.downcase`をDBに格納するのではなく、値の参照時に持ってくる、などです。

その上でバルクアップデートが必要であれば、[activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import)を使うことをお勧めします。
コードについては[On Duplicate Key Update](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/On-Duplicate-Key-Update)や関連記事等を参考にしてください。

参考：
http://paranishian.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/11/06/142412
http://qiita.com/ysk_1031/items/d669157225e67d3a40bf

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。「良い書き方」とは例えば同じ値であれば、全件を `find_each` と `update` で回すよりも `update_all`の方が効率が良いなど明らかな優位性のあるものがないかと思い質問いたしました。現状では定期的に発生する処理ではないので`find_each`の方法を取ることにします。